# How to use List of tuples from C# in TypeScrypt

Tags: c#, json, typescript

I want to get list of tuples from server and use them in TypeScript on client.

Problem is that I don't know how to declare list of tuples in TypeScript?
Message property on client is null even when should not be.

This are list of tuples in entity on server

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> Messages { get; set; }
```

Return List of entities in Json (there are more properties but to simplify):

```
[  
   {  
      "id":93,
      "messages":[  
         {  
            "item1":"A1",
            "item2":"Hello"
         },
         {  
            "item1":"A2",
            "item2":"World"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":94,
      "messages":null
   }
]
```

I try to create same property in TypeScript like this:

```
messages: { item1: string, item2: string }[];
```

All other properites are fine, problem is only with messages.

Comment: Could you post the complete type for the JSON ? not just `messages`. And specifically what is not ok. I t should work

Comment: @Paritosh that is something you can always do but you should always avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type should work. With the sample data, this has the expected output:

```
interface Item {
    id: number;
    messages: {
        item1: string;
        item2: string;
    }[];
}

let typed: Item[] = json;
for (const item of typed) {
    console.log(item.id);
    if(!item.messages) continue;
    for(const message of item.messages){
        console.log(`${message.item1} - ${message.item2}`)
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help.